# Bootable hard drive to install Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, operating-systems, bootable-media

What to write onto hard drive, so that it will be bootable and it will be possible to install operating system (like Windwos XP) from it onto itself?

I have old notebook with broken CD-ROM and which can't boot from USB.

**UPDATE**

I have connected hard drive to my desktop. Now I want to write something on it so that it will be (A) bootable and (B) contain system distribution.

I can't install OS on this drive while it is inside desktop, since desktop has different hardware etc.

So I need some small bootstrap operating system and so on.

**UPDATE 2**

Yes, actually I need to know how to make HDD bootable too. I know I need to make "active" partition and write boot to bootsector. But what next?

Comment: So you're able to access the drive? Or can boot using a floppy or something?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? Do you simply want to know how to make it bootable, or do you want to install the OS to the very same disk you are installing it from?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to install it on your desktop.  If you disconnect all your good hard drives and install windows to the laptop hard drive.  Then go into the **Device Manager** and find the **IDE** Controller.  Then you need to change them from whatever they are to **Standard** mode.  If it asks to reboot after the first one say *NO* then repeat for any other IDE controller entries.  Shutdown the computer and move the hard drive back to the laptop and try and boot it.